# 'Repeated' field type doesn't display properly(css not applying)+sonata admin bundle

Tags: sonata-admin

I tried to add Password field of type 'repeated' since it requires confirmation :

```php
 ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                'validation_groups' => array('Default'),
                'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
               // 'attr'=>array('class'=>'sonata-ba-field-container')
            ))
```

But it doesn't show in formatted way.Two fields overlapping each other (Since CSS not applied). Any way to apply default sonata admin bundle theme for this field?

Comment: This is a bug. I will create a PR, which will fix this issue in the coming days.

Answer (score 1):

This is Sonata bug.

You can fix it by applying these changes: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1093/files

I`ve created a [PR](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1093) so if the patch will be ok, it will be merged to master branch.

**UPDATE**

The fix was merged with master branch so in master should be ok now.